# What is the difference between natural theology and transcendental theology?

Tags: theology, terminology

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_theology),

> Natural theology, once also termed physico-theology, is a type of
> theology and deism that seeks to provide arguments for theological
> topics (such as the existence of a deity) based on reason and the
> discoveries of science, the project of arguing for the existence of
> God on the basis of observed so-called natural facts, and through
> natural phenomena viewed as divine, or complexities of nature seen as
> evidence of a divine plan (see predestination) or Will of God, which
> includes nature itself. This distinguishes it from revealed theology, which is based on scripture and/or religious experiences, also from **transcendental theology**, which is based on **a priori reasoning**.

Isn't a priori reasoning included in natural theology ([see SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-theology/))? Why are natural and transcendental theology being distinguished from each other then?

Answer (score 2):

From your quote, natural theology *includes reason **and the discoveries of science***, whereas trascendental theology does not need to include such discoveries. See also the SEP entry you link (bold mine):

> the project of arguing for the existence of God **on the basis of observed natural facts.**

Observed natural facts are not needed for rational arguments in trascendental theology; see [Kant's original definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_theology):

> Transcendental theology aims either at inferring the existence of a Supreme Being from a general experience, **without any closer reference to the world to which this experience belongs**, and in this case it is called cosmotheology; or it endeavours to cognize the existence of such a being, through mere conceptions, **without the aid of experience**, and is then termed ontotheology

Answer (score 0):

From [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-religion/):

> Kant’s distinction between Deism and Theism is intertwined with his
> distinction between Transcendental Theology and Natural Theology
> (A631/B659–A632/B660). The meaning of these terms, however, are not
> what some have assumed (e.g., Wood 1991).
>
> In his Lectures on the Philosophical Doctrine of Religion, Kant
> defines “Transcendental Theology” as the “recognition [Kenntniss] of
> God by means of concepts of pure reason” (AK 28:596 [1821]). These
> concepts are not, however, the pure concepts of the understanding, but
> rather what he calls the four “classes of concepts” (B110): namely,
> quantity, quality, relation and modality. More precisely, Kant sees
> Transcendental Theology as a consequence of reason’s quest for the
> unconditioned condition, with its concepts of God corresponding to the
> unconditioned for each of the “classes of concepts”, namely: ens
> summum (quality), ens entium (quantity), ens originarium (modality),
> and ens realissimum (relation).
>
> As Transcendental Theology employs no “information” about the
> conditioned (i.e., the created world), it is without the resources
> needed to develop a concept of God “in concreto” (AK 28:1020 [1817]).
> Absent the “materials for the concept of God from empirical principles
> and empirical information” (AK 28:1020 [1817]), Transcendental
> Theology can do no more than attribute to God “what is true of him as
> a thing in general” (AK 28:1020 [1817]). That is, its concept of God
> is just that of unconditioned quality, quantity, modality, and
> relation.
>
> Absent all “information” about the conditioned, Transcendental
> Theology is thus without the resources to develop the concept of God
> used in either Natural or Moral Theology, i.e, the “wise author of
> nature” or the judge and “ruler” of nature, respectively (AK 28:452
> [1968], AK 28:596 [1821], AK 28:1002 [1817]). Consequently, Kant
> claims that Transcendental Theology is inadequate, yielding “only a
> silhouette of a theology” (AK 28:605, AK 28:452 [1968]). Its
> conception of God is “useless” (AK 28:596 [1821]), “unusable” (AK
> 28:452 [1968]), and “quite superfluous to us” (AK 28:1020 [1817]). For
> it provides us only with the god of Deism, and according to the
> lectures, this God is “useless” and “unusable”.
>
> Hence, despite the familiar-seeming term, Kant does not mean by
> “Deism” how it was typically used by the British. Their Deism is
> rather much more akin to what Kant means by “Theism”, as the outcome
> of Natural (vs. Transcendental) Theology. That is, Kant maintains in
> the Critique of Pure Reason that our picture of nature as having
> systematic unity commits us to seeing nature “as if” it were created
> by a “Wise Author” (A644/B672–A645/B673).